# Iterating over C++ objects wrapped in Python via pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pointers, pybind11

I have C++ code defining a `curves` class, a `curve` class and a `point` class, I'm trying to write Python bindings for those classes via pybind11 and use them in Python.

The pybind11 bindings for these classes look like this:

```
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(mymodule, m) {
    py::class_<_point>(m, "_point")
        .def(py::init<double, double>()) 
        .def_readwrite("next", &point::next)
        .def_readwrite("prev", &point::prev)
        .def_readonly("x1", &point::x1)
        .def_readonly("x2", &point::x2);
    py::class_<curve>(m, "curve")
        .def(py::init<point*>()) //constructor 1
        .def(py::init()) //constructor 2
        .def_readwrite("first", &curve::first)
        .def_readwrite("last", &curve::last)
        .def_readwrite("next", &curve::next)
        .def_readwrite("prev", &curve::prev);
    py::class_<curves>(m, "curves")
        .def(py::init()) 
        .def_readwrite("first", &curves::first)
        .def_readwrite("last", &curves::last);
}
```

In C++ I can iterate over a `curves` object which is made up of `curve` 
which in turn is made up of `point` objects in the following way:

```
for(curve *c=curves_pointer->first; c; c=c->next) {
      for(point *p=c->first; p; p=p->next) {
          cout << p->x1 << "," <<p->x2 << std::endl;
      }
}
```

In Python, I can for example access a single point with `curves_instance.last.first.x1`, but I don't know how to iterate over all curves, points etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just `def` a simple generator:

```
def iterate_from(item):
     while item is not None:
         yield item
         item = item.next
```

Which would allow you to write code like bellow (it is just a concept, update it if needed)

```
for c in iterate_from(curves_instance.first):
    for p in iterate_from(c.first):
        print p.x1, ",", p.x2
```

Answer (score 13):

I think the correct answer would have been
to implement `__iter__` by using `pybind11::make_iterator`. An example is provided [here](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/tests/test_sequences_and_iterators.cpp).

I think it's `py::make_iterator`:

```
.def("__iter__", [](const Sequence &s) { return py::make_iterator(s.begin(), s.end()); },
                         py::keep_alive<0, 1>() /* Essential: keep object alive while iterator exists */)
```

Comment: I followed this exactly and got: `TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was: (self: pybind11_builtins.iterator) -> YAML::detail::iterator_value`. Any clue what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Figured it out. The return type from the iterator was not `YAML::Node` as I thought it was, so I had to add a binding for `YAML::detail::iterator_value`

Comment: If `Sequence` is a custom class, how would you deal with both const and non-const overloads for the iterator types `begin()` and `end()`?